# Automatically change README badge's version once app is updated

Tags: flutter, mobile, markdown, documentation, readme

I have a badge on my project's README file to show what version the app is on:

```
<a href="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id={app-package-name}">
    <img
        src="https://img.shields.io/badge/GooglePlayStore-{app-version}-brightgreen" />
</a>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to have a badge that gets the version from the store, so I don't have to manually change it every time. [flutter_app_version_checker](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_version_checker) does something similar to check if the app is up to date or not, so I'm wondering if there is a similar solution to these README badges. Alternatively, a badge that gets the version from the pubspec.yaml file would also work, since I'm working with Flutter.